# NullReferenceException when using "new oracleConnection" in x64?

Tags: c#, oracle, nullreferenceexception

I am using vs2008 .NET framework3.5 Oracle10g

Getting this error for the line

```
conn=new oracleConnection(oraString);
```

same code works on WinXp and win7(32 bit) not for win7(64 bit)

Comment: Do you have the 64bit ora client installed on the wint(64bit) box or the 32bit client?

Comment: Have you verified the value of `oraString` in a debugger, or with logging, on the problematic systems?

Comment: Have you referenced the `Oracle.DataAccess` dll properly ? check on that, maybe the dll is not being loaded

Comment: Both System.Data.OracleClient and Oracle.DataAccess references are added..

Answer (score 0):

go to menu **project**> yourProject **properties**> **build**> change **platformtarget** to x64

maybe it works;

Comment: In the Build>Platform has only one option i.e Active(any CPU)

Comment: public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //database connection
            oradb = "Data Source=XE;User Id=system;Password=tiger;";
            try
            {
                conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

Comment: Same Connection String worked old os ..Contents of file tnsnames.ora are also updated